# Symfony & Doctrine - Complete profile after user registration

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Symfony 4 app, and I am using the FOSUser bundle for my user system at present.

I would like to add a complete your profile feature after the user first registers their account. Perhaps it continues to appear until a condition is met or a time is expired.

**To begin with what should I add to my User class to flag the user needs to be redirected to /profile/complete ?**

ie. Is one extra field required ... completeProfile with methods setCompleteProfile and hasCompleteProfile?

**How can I set a condition or time limit on when the user doesn't need to be flagged for complete profile?**

ie. is this done in the controller? what symfony service can be used?

Comment: I think I will only need it in the ProfileController

Comment: you could write one function in your controller where you check and redirect the user or not and call this check in each action

Comment: just add a boolean field to test against

Comment: OK so add completedProfile to my User entity?

Comment: why not, but dont expect anything from happening magically. There is no inbuilt function so Its custom logic, and so its custom code - you can name and programm it however you want but pls dont ask SO for code for you

Comment: it´s all good :) But asking a question on SO needs at least `what did you try` and `where did it fail` and yours hasneither

Comment: OK all good. I will try to structure my questions a bit different next time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a $ registredAt and $ hasCompleteProfile property in your Entity App\Entity\User or something else?
You can do like this, in your Controller ...

```
public function yourController(User $user) {
        if (!$user->getHasCompleteProfile()) {  // Getters of $hasCompleteProfile inside App\Entity\User
            $completeProfileLimt = 4;           // In months or days, 4 is just and example
            $now = new \Datetime();
            $userRegistredDate = $user->getRegistredAt();

            $elapsedTime = $now - $userRegistredDate; // You can not do it like this but it's an example

            if ($elapsedTime > $completeProfileLimt) {
                // Your action
            }

            // Your Response Return
        }

        // Your Response Return
    }
```